# onmouseover doesn't work, function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an icon which needs to put the password_field that it is in to a textfield and vise versa.

```
<i class="password_icon fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true" onmouseover="mouseOverPassword()" onmouseout="mouseOutPassword()"></i>
```

But when I hover over the icon it says that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseOutPassword is not defined
at HTMLElement.onmouseout ((index):1)
```

Even though they are in the .js file that I include:

```
function mouseOverPassword() {
    var obj = $("#passworldField");
    obj.type = "text";
}
function mouseOutPassword() {
    var obj = $("#passworldField");
    obj.type = "password";
}'
```

The functions are in a $(document).ready function. I can't really find out why it doesn't work. And yes, the .js is included on the page.

Comment: Good thing to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the functions are scoped into another one, in your case in the `$(document).ready` they are not visible directly into the html. You need to bind them via Javascript. Get your element by `id` or `name` or something else and attach via that approach.

```
<i id="iEl" class="password_icon fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i>

...

$('#iEl').on('mouseover', mouseOverPassword);
$('#iEl').on('mouseout', mouseOutPassword);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best way would be to move your functions out of the `$(document).ready` and define the `mouseover` event inside of your `$(document).ready` instead of doing it directly into your HTML.

```
$( "#element" ).mouseover(function() {
  mouseOverPassword() 
}
```

Same for `mouseleave`, check the jQuery docs here: https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Another thing would be to completely remove you `$(document).ready` and place your `<script src="file.js"></script>` to the bottom of your page, just before the `</body>` closing tag.